# How do i make a block that the user will be able to put positive integer numbers only in Python

Tags: python

I start learning python, and in an exercise it asks to create a program that only postive intger number will be accepted.

This is what I have written:

```py
while True:
    number = input('Type an integer positive number: ')
    try:
        number = int(number)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print ('Value not accepted')
        break
```

How can I add in my block the >0 check ?

Comment: `if number < 0?

Answer (score 0):

You could throw an exception using `raise`.

```
while True:
    number = input('Type an integer positive number: ')
    try:
        number = int(number)
        if number < 0 :
            raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        print ('Value not accepted')
        break
```

**Output**

```
Type an integer positive number: 3
Type an integer positive number: 4
Type an integer positive number: -4
Value not accepted
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to check if is bigger than 0 before the first break.

```
while True:
    number = input('Type an integer positive number: ')
    try:
        number = int(number)
        if number > 0:
             break
    except ValueError:
        print ('Value not accepted')
        break
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include an explanation. Code only answers are not considered high quality.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you wanna keep your exception handling as it is so my suggestion would be:

```
while True:
    number = input('Type an integer positive number: ')
    try:
        number = int(number)
        if number <= 0:
            raise ValueError('Negative number or zero entered.')
        break
    except ValueError as ve:
        print(ve)
        break
```

I hope this helps you to finish your task and you continue to have fun learning Python. I'm also new to this but Python is so much fun! :)

Answer (score 0):

use continus to let user input again.

```
while True:
    number = input('Type an integer positive number: ')
    try:
        number = int(number)
        if number < 0:
            continue
        else:
            break
    except ValueError:
        print('Value not accepted')
        break
```

Comment: You can just do `if number <= 0: break`. Otherwise the loop will continue anyway. No need to explicitly state `continue`

Comment: As it is currently written your code does not work. Maybe test before submitting?